# Tableview gets filled correctly sometimes and most of the times it is empty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a question regarding loading data from a database (a list of dishes) into a tableview. Now follows the piece of code where I think maybe something goes wrong:

```
//get the data from database and put it in dishesJSON
let dishesJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

//getting the JSON array dishes from the response
let dishes : NSArray = dishesJSON["dishes"] as! NSArray

//create temporary array
var temp : NSArray

//create temporary variable of type string
var tempstring : String

for i in 0 ..< dishes.count {
    temp = dishes[i] as! NSArray
    tempstring = temp[1] as! String
    self.arrayOfDishes.append(tempstring)
}
print(self.arrayOfDishes)
```

Now when I run the app, I always see that it prints the list of dishes correctly in the console. But the weird thing is that sometimes the tableview is empty and sometimes the tableview is correctly filled with the list of dishes. The weird thing is that when I filled the tableview with a predefined list of strings, it always worked, but now it does not seem to work sometimes. So I am pretty sure there is no problem in how I defined the table and fill it with an array of strings. I think the problem is maybe somewhere here. If the problem is not in here, I can look further to find the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: You can actually debug by checking the delegates calls at `numberOfRows`

Comment: You need to call `reloadData()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you grab this from a web Service or not , but try

```
 for i in 0 ..< dishes.count {
    temp = dishes[i] as! NSArray
    tempstring = temp[1] as! String
    self.arrayOfDishes.append(tempstring)
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {  // as it may be in a background thread
 self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job :)